# How to display the complete images from AWSS3 bucket in iOS SWIFT?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

I am using the following code for downloading the list of the images from the AWS S3 bucket and display in a tableView. I tried a lot of solutions but there is no use.

```
func listS3Objects() {
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast2, identityPoolId:identityID)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast2, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration

    AWSS3.register(with: configuration!, forKey: "defaultKey")
    let s3 = AWSS3.s3(forKey: "defaultKey")

    let listRequest: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
    listRequest.bucket = bucketName

    s3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        print("Object result = \(task.result)")

        print("Object contents = \(task.result?.contents)")
        for object in (task.result?.contents)! {

            print("Object key = \(object.key!)")
            self.imagesArray.append(object)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.ImageList_Table.reloadData()
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your goal? In your code you only load the list of objects. If you want to download the real images you need a downloadRequest after you get the list.

Comment: not getting the data to show or store in array @Chris

Comment: Whats the output of `print("Object result = \(task.result)")`

Comment: Object result = nil

Comment: Please look at my answer and try the code. Now you are able to get your output or if not you will get an error message. This is much easier to debug, if you get an error. The most common error is AccessDenied error, if your permissions are not set properly.
In your case I guess you have to use `s3` instead of my `AWSS3.default()`

Comment: I'm getting==>>> "Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSServiceErrorDomain Code=11 "(null)" UserInfo={HostId=jIXYKVE7fuSqUsK6yHrKHbUAUnt6v3XLct1Eq0eEpid9r+Ib4+eI1KaEtonIuejeCUiy+8PvHSk=, Message=Access Denied, Code=AccessDenied, RequestId=4F0066D8E6003471}

Comment: You have to set s3:ListBucket in IAM for your role

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205646/discussion-between-deepak-yadeedya-and-chris).

Comment: No problem. Please mark answer as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding to [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) Amazon recommend to use the newer Version  [ListObjectsV2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html), when developing applications.

An example request can look like this

```
let listObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsV2Request()
listObjectsRequest?.bucket = "your bucket"
//listObjectsRequest?.prefix = prefix. //If you want to have a prefix
//listObjectsRequest?.delimiter = delimiter //If you want to have a delimiter
AWSS3.default().listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest!) { (output, error) in
  if let error = error{
     print(error)
  }
  if let output = output{
     print(output)
  }
```

**Note :** To use this operation in an AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policy, you must have permissions to perform the s3:ListBucket action